# predict_generator gives "Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes."

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, keras, image-classification

I have trained my model on the very big dataset (approx 1200000 train images, and 15000 classes) using Keras' `flow_from_directory` method. I have successfully trained my model using `fit_generator`. But, now I am facing the problem for `predict_generator`.

I got the following error while executing `predict_generator`:

> "Found 0 images belonging to 0 classes."

However, I have converted my train image dataset into the subdirectory based on class labels. But, for test dataset, I don't have any labels. 
So how can I overcome this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Make a folder Structure.

For instance:

```
Training_Data
       |
        ---Cat
       |
       -----Dog
```

Because keras expect your folder in catag